# Upgrade to 13.04 dialog still offering Development Release (ALPHA), not stable one

Tags: upgrade

I ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` then `sudo update-manager -d`.

But the upgrade dioalog propose the 13.04 Development version, not the stable one...see below :
[image]

How to upgrade to the official stable 13.04 release ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to look for `-d` versions anymore. It might come up normally.

But if not, do these steps:

Open the Ubuntu Software Center and under *Edit* > *Software Sources* > *Updates* you will find a `Notify me of a new Ubuntu version` option, from the drop box select *For any new version*.

[image]

Comment: By looking at this guide http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade I can see that what they call "dev version" is the latest 13.04...So I had no problems actually :)